# I can't add the card list together in python

Tags: python

I need help with this. I got everything done except number 3. How can I added together and average the value?

1. Generate the 5 cards and store them in a list
   2.Pass the entire 5-card list to a new function “display_hand” that will take the list as input and go through the list one at a time and call your display_face_value function
   3.Pass the entire 5-card list to a different function “hand_stats” that will take the list as input and display the total value of the cards added together and the average value of the cards in the hand (divide by 5).  !Be sure to label the output!

I am not sure how to send the value to hand_stats 
I keep getting the error `"NameError: name 'card' is not defined"`

```
def deal_hand():  

    print ("Deal Hand")
    print ("------------")
    cards = []
    cards.append(random.randint(1, 13))
    cards.append(random.randint(1, 13))
    cards.append(random.randint(1, 13))
    cards.append(random.randint(1, 13))
    cards.append(random.randint(1, 13))

    display_hand(cards)
    hand_stats(cards)

def display_hand(hand):
    print ("The 5-card hand is: ")
    for card in hand:
        face_value(card)
```

it runs display_hand but it doesn't run hand_stats
Thank you guys

Comment: In `hand_stats` function, it is not finding `card` defined. I think it is the issue, if detail error with line number is provided may be it will be helpful.

Comment: How would I fixed this, I don't understand it.

Comment: you can try `sum(hand)` since parameter is named `hand` .

Comment: I did it but is not showing anything:

Comment: The 5-card hand is: 
Ace
Five
Five
Queen
Eight
The Sum is:

Comment: Try `print(sum(hand))`

Comment: That worked perfectly! Can somebody explain me the define thing? Which I think I am not understanding because I wasn't defining it right.

Comment: The function parameter name is `hand` and card was not defined. For more details: http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html#variable-scope-and-lifetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, the function `hand_stats` does not have `card` defined it may be the cause, instead `hand` is the function variable name passed. So, you may try `sum(hand)` instead:

```
def hand_stats(hand):
    print(sum(hand))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
def hand_stats(card):
```

instead of

```
def hand_stats(hand):
```